# Different results from Integrate and NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I have an expression which has an analytical integral. But `NIntegrate` and `Integrate` gives different values. Why?

Mathematica version 11.2

Code and results:

```
w = 1 + 2/3 I; 
t0 = 1; 
n = 15; 
int1 = Integrate[Exp[I w t]/Sqrt[t^2 - t0^2] t^(-2 (n + 1)), {t, t0, ∞}]

(* 1/2 MeijerG[{{-15, 1/2, 1}, {}}, {{}, {-(31/2)}}, 1296/169 E^(4 I ArcTan[3/2]), 2] *)

N[int1, 30]

(* 0.0629985988586534758877615553402 - 0.0506478034220383880351981581571 I*)

int2 = 
  NIntegrate[Exp[I w t]/Sqrt[t^2 - t0^2] t^(-2 (n + 1)), {t, t0, ∞}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]

(* 0.0597416653055238422645694709489 + 0.0963766277967734573626260768145 I *)
```

Answer (score 10):

When [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) doesn't issue errors, and using higher precision converges, than the most likely issue is that [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) couldn't figure out how to handle branch cut issues correctly. One trick that I like to use in such cases is to replace a problematic parameter with a constant, integrate, and then replace the constant with the parameter after the integration. This approach works for your example:

```
int = Integrate[
    Exp[I EulerGamma t]/Sqrt[t^2 - t0^2] t^(-2(n+1)),
    {t, t0, Infinity}
];
int //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2} \pi  G_{1,3}^{2,0}\left(\frac{\gamma ^2}{4}|
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \frac{33}{2} \\
>  0,16,\frac{1}{2} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)+\frac{i \gamma  \pi  \left(-1187907847944849195179530749609375 \gamma  \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+204811697921525723306815646484375 \gamma ^3 \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma
>    )-10619865818153185652945996484375 \gamma ^5 \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma
>    )+262968105973316978072948484375 \gamma ^7 \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma
>    )-3811131970627782290912296875 \gamma ^9 \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+36296494958359831342021875
>    \gamma ^{11} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )-244915620501753247921875 \gamma ^{13} \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+1234868674798755871875 \gamma ^{15} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma
>    )-4842622254112768125 \gamma ^{17} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+15248922977413125 \gamma ^{19} \pi
>     \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )-39607592149125 \gamma ^{21} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+86973193125 \gamma
>    ^{23} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )-165663225 \gamma ^{25} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+283185 \gamma
>    ^{27} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )-465 \gamma ^{29} \pi  \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+\gamma ^{31} \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_0(\gamma )+3672223350604861716931018752000000-439555539574028925954719543981250
>    \gamma ^2+21860810199430579221603421162500 \gamma ^4-534364371662614944284197113750 \gamma
>    ^6+7699969665250582145431005000 \gamma ^8-73107664089026909823731250 \gamma
>    ^{10}+492396088595579434129500 \gamma ^{12}-2479717198178026269750 \gamma
>    ^{14}+9716498724447673200 \gamma ^{16}-30578708495906550 \gamma ^{18}+79392252095100 \gamma
>    ^{20}-174283041330 \gamma ^{22}+331901640 \gamma ^{24}-567318 \gamma ^{26}+932 \gamma ^{28}-2
>    \gamma ^{30}\right) J_1(\gamma )}{32891354616711691270902251520000000}-\frac{i \gamma ^2 \pi 
>    \left(\gamma ^{28} (928-465 \pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma ))+\gamma ^{30} (\pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma
>    )-2)+9 \gamma ^{26} (31465 \pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-62826)-225 \gamma ^{24} (736281 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-1470032)-61425 \gamma ^{20} (644812245 \pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma
>    )-1286776016)+45 \gamma ^{22} (1932737625 \pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-3858073682)+326025 \gamma
>    ^{18} (46772250525 \pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-93299878898)-20539575 \gamma ^{16} (235770324075
>    \pi  \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-470043834848)+40186125 \gamma ^{14} (30728732237775 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-61214081542046)-3656937375 \gamma ^{12} (66972877954125 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-133262038442432)+201131555625 \gamma ^{10} (180461463869115 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-358448255769854)-19912024006875 \gamma ^8 (191398522285425 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-379070999744432)+139384168048125 \gamma ^6 (1886642576813475 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-3716840811465638)-407698691540765625 (2913690606794775 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-4503599627370496)+27179912769384375 \gamma ^2 (7535406741710625 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-14210240345493274)-1294281560446875 \gamma ^4 (8205220674307125 \pi 
>    \pmb{H}_1(\gamma )-15982961194617584)\right) J_0(\gamma
>    )}{32891354616711691270902251520000000}+\frac{9694845 i \gamma  \left(1-\frac{5 \gamma
>    ^2}{29}+\frac{7 \gamma ^4}{783}-\frac{13 \gamma ^6}{58725}+\frac{13 \gamma
>    ^8}{4052025}-\frac{13 \gamma ^{10}}{425462625}+\frac{\gamma ^{12}}{4850273925}-\frac{\gamma
>    ^{14}}{961970995125}+\frac{\gamma ^{16}}{245302603756875}-\frac{\gamma
>    ^{18}}{77901098307361875}+\frac{\gamma ^{20}}{29991922848334321875}-\frac{\gamma
>    ^{22}}{13658321665131450181875}+\frac{\gamma ^{24}}{7170618874194011345484375}-\frac{\gamma
>    ^{26}}{4194812041403496637108359375}+\frac{\gamma
>    ^{28}}{2554640533214729451998990859375}-\frac{\gamma
>    ^{30}}{1187907847944849195179530749609375}\right) \pi }{134217728}$

Assuming that all instances of [`EulerGamma`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerGamma) come from my insertion of [`EulerGamma`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EulerGamma) into the integral, we can do:

```
N[int /. EulerGamma -> w, 30]
```

> 0.0597416653055238422640336356729 + 0.0963766277967734573617915628157 I

which reproduces the [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) result.

Comment: Interesting!  That was not a result I was expecting.

Comment: Note: people usually use `Zeta[3]` instead of `EulerGamma` (because the latter appears much more often than the former).

Comment: Thanks for very fast answer. It is really interesting solution.