# Numerical integral or Numerical value of a symbolic integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm new to numerical integration. Why is this code wrong?

```
N[Integrate[(b^2 Sin[θ]^3 Cos[ϕ]^2)/(b^2 Cos[ϕ]^2  Sin[θ]^2 + a^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 Sin[θ]^2 +
 a^2 b^2 Cos[θ]^2), {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

$a$ and $b$ are real values.

Comment: If you know what $a$ and $b$ are beforehand, use `NIntegrate` instead of integrating and then finding the numeric value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) assumptions, e.g.:

```
integrand = (b^2 Sin[θ]^3 Cos[ϕ]^2)/(b^2 Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[θ]^2+a^2 Sin[ϕ]^2 Sin[θ]^2+a^2 b^2 Cos[θ]^2);

Integrate[
    integrand,
    {θ,0,π},
    {ϕ,0,2 π},
    Assumptions->(a|b) ∈ Reals
]
```

> $Aborted

However, I wasn't patient enough to let the above finish. An alternate method (e.g., as mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165170/45431)) is to substitute real constants for the parameters, and then substitute back. For example:

```
f[a_, b_] = Integrate[
    integrand /. {a->EulerGamma, b->Khinchin},
    {θ, 0, π},
    {ϕ, 0, 2 π}
] /. {EulerGamma->a, Khinchin->b}; //AbsoluteTiming

f[a, b] //TeXForm
```

> {17.7305, Null}
>
> $\frac{4 \pi  b \left(\frac{a \sqrt{b^2-a^2}
>    \left(E\left(\frac{1-b^2}{a^2-b^2}\right)-E\left(\sin
>    ^{-1}(a)|\frac{1-b^2}{a^2-b^2}\right)\right)}{a^2-1}+b\right)}{b^2-a^2}$

When using this approach it is best to compare the numerical answer with the proposed answer:

```
f[1/4, 1/3] //N
f[11/4, 2/3] //N
```

> 6.58407 + 0. I
>
> 1.16785 + 0. I

Versus:

```
g = With[
    {i = integrand /. {a->#1, b->#2}},
    Function[NIntegrate[i, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}]]
];

g[1/4, 1/3]
g[11/4, 2/3]
```

> 6.58407
>
> 1.16785

Comment: Thank you! A question. Why do you use the Euler and Kinchin constants?  Could it be any other constant?

Comment: @user3321 I use constants that I hope don't appear in the final answer, since my final replacement rule eliminates those constants from the answer. If one of those constants are supposed to be in the answer, then the result would be wrong. For example, if I had used $\pi$, then my final answer would not have included $\pi$, and it would have been wrong.